# Access php array index issue

Tags: php, arrays

After use fgetcsv() function I get an array, then I use a foreach() and I get a "simple" associative array like:

```
Array  
(  
  [ix,radical,variant,simplified,pinyin,english,strokes] => 1,一,,,yi1,one,1  
)
```

Then I try to access any element and I fail:

```
 echo $record['ix'];
```

> Notice: Undefined index: ix

```
echo next($record);  // return nothing!
```

Maybe is offtopic (not centred in php language) but I'm using some lib (not necessary of course from PHP commenter in http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php)

```
<?php

require "..\CsvImporter.lib.php";

$importer = new CsvImporter('my_route\\my.csv',true); 
while($records = $importer->get()) 
{   
    // debug
    print_r($records[0]);
    exit; 

    foreach ($records as $record)   
    {
      \\ ..
    }
}
```

And my screen output is

```
Array ( [ix,radical,variant,simplified,pinyin,english,strokes] => 1,一,,,yi1,one,1 )
```

My data:

```
ix,radical,variant,simplified,pinyin,english,strokes
1,一,,,yi1,one,1
2,丨,,,gun3,line,1
3,丶,,,zhu3,dot,1
```

So how is possible I'm unable to access any key ?

Comment: Please properly print your array with key and value.

Comment: Milap, that was my array!

Comment: @Boctulus I think you probably want to show us your code how you tried to construct your array, because your key is not `ix` but `ix,radical,variant,simplified,pinyin,english,strokes`. Show: your current code to build this array and what you expect to get

Comment: Your array is not correct. Kindly review it again. That's a wrong format of array. Php dosent makes syntax error.

Comment: Try `print_r($record); exit;` and see what it prints out.

Comment: @Boctulus Kindly have a look at my answer

Comment: check with your csv it is not a proper array format. or give us a sample csv of yours.

Comment: @CaptainHypertext : done (since I post this quesion)

Comment: @Vinie  done! please check

Comment: when you write ` print_r($records[0]);   exit; ` what output you get ?

Comment: @Vinie     Array ( [ix,radical,variant,simplified,pinyin,english,strokes] => 1,一,,,yi1,one,1 ) so now I'm thinking 'ix,radical,variant,simplified,pinyin,english,strokes' is the key  and '一,,,yi1,one,1' the only value :)

Comment: See my answer if i got your problem right

Answer (score 1):

As you posted your data above. Your csv importer giving you each row with comma. So you need to explode it then use however you want to use

Example code \

```
 $i=0;
 while($records = $importer->get()) 
 {   
      if($i>0) //skip first row it is heading
      {
           $data = explode(',',$records);
           print_r($data);
          // now `$data[0]` contains `ix` value for your first csv row and so on
      }
      $i++;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do it in a lot of ways, but I was wondering why couldn't access that array in particular.  Good answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

I used some lib and the default delimiter was "\t" so something like **'ix,radical,variant,simplified,pinyin,english,strokes'** was THE key and **'一,,,yi1,one,1'** the only value

Now, I see the problem I can do it easy:

```
$f = 'file.csv';
$separator = ',';

$file = file_get_contents($f);     

// bi-dimensional array
$regs = array_map(function($reg){return (explode($separator,$reg));},explode("\n",$file));
```

Thanks all!